# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top not working in side my div id="content"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the bootstrap navbar-fixed-top I have a bootstrap navbar in side my `id="content"` div, but when I add **navbar-fixed-top** to here

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-shadow">
```

The navbar goes on top of every thing else.

**Question:** How am I able to get it so only the content that is in side my `id="content"` is able to scroll under the navbar?

> Note: Links have been updated now with working code, Special Thanks to
>    [@Av Avt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1645830/av-avt), and thank you for every one else who had ago.

**Code Example Previews**

[CodePen Code Preview Click Here](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/bdaGro)

[CodePen Full View Click Here](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/full/bdaGro/)

**HTML**

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="holder.js/48x48" />
                </div>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Administration
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<nav id="column-left">
<div id="profile">
    <ul class="media-list">
        <li class="media">
            <div class="media-left">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="media-object img-circle" src="holder.js/64x64" alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">John Doe</h4>
            <p>Administrator</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul id="menu">

<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>

<li>
    <a class="parent"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></i> <span>Drop Down Menu</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="parent">Sub Drop Down Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>    
</nav>

<!-- navbar-fixed-top not work correct when have it in my content id -->    

<div id="content">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-shadow">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a type="button" id="button-menu" class="navbar-brand"><i class="fa fa-indent fa-lg"></i></a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-lg"></i> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Logout <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="panel-title">Calender</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.0/holder.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

From comment:

I just would like to be able to use the navbar-fixed-top feature bootstrap has but instead of it being at top of page like in there examples would like it to be inside my content id. And the header div all ways at top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following css rules in your css:

```
#content{
  position: relative;
}

#content .navbar-fixed-top{
  position: absolute;
}
```

After you had the navbar at the top of `#content`, give `#content .main-content` a `max-height` as the view port height subtract `<header>`'s height, and give it `overflow: auto;`:

```
#content .main-content{
  padding-top: 70px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
  overflow: auto;

  /*move the 40px padding (and all bottom/top padding) of #content to .main_content instead */
  padding-bottom: 40px; 
}
```

The `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-shadow">` will continue to behave as a normal `.navbar-fixed-top`, except it now only stick at the top of `#content`.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPpOpX

Comment: I cannot scroll divs that is inside the content id back up and down seems to just stay under navbar.

Comment: Ah, I see what you want. You want to change the #content div into the actual view port for the website, with scroll-able contents within it and a navbar fixed at that position on top of the content, right. Will need quite a lot of hack. Last time I did a website like that it only cause constant trouble again and again later in the project, with little benefit. But anyway I'll look for a solution for you.

Comment: Yes I just want to be able to use the navbar-fixed-top feature bootstrap has but instead of it being at top of page like in there examples would like it to be inside my content id. the header div all ways at top.

Comment: Hmm.... if your `<header>` size never change there's a very quick solution by adding `max-height: calc(100vh - 70px);  overflow: auto;` to the `#content .main-content`, like in the updated demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPpOpX . But if the height varies it would be quite sotisficated....

Comment: Getting close but the navbar moves with it also needs to stay where it is.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to save my changes +_+ This is the correct demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPpOpX The added css are all at the bottom of the css panel.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution :**

```
#content .navbar-fixed-top{
 width: calc(100% - 245px);
 top: inherit;
 right: inherit; 
 left: inherit; 
 bottom:inherit;
 }
```

you also need to give your #column-left position fixed if you want your sidebar to be fixed also

Comment: Tried that but everything else moves as well. Updated: http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/bdaGro

Comment: give your 
.container-fluid{padding-top:60px;}

one more thing you have to manage some other elements by your own , bootstrap not gonna do everything for you a little understanding of css is required !

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want `#content` should be scrollable and the rest everything should be fixed. For this I have done some changes in `html` and `css`

1. I moved navigation `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-shadow">` to `#header`.
2. Added `navbar-fixed-top` class to the header `#header`. This will fix the `header` to the window, only if you follow the step #3.
3. Removed `position: relative` CSS for `#header`.
4. Using CSS, added the `top padding` to the `body` which is equal to the height of `#header`. If you want you can do this using JS also.

[Here is the working example](http://codepen.io/masoomulhaqs/full/YwXzXZ/)

Comment: Do you want the navbar after administration section?

Comment: In side the id="content" where it is now. In my example.

Comment: I believe this is what you are expecting, http://codepen.io/masoomulhaqs/full/WrvNVV/

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `navbar-fixed-top` and calculate the scrollable height using jQuery:

```
var h = $(document).height();
$('#content').css({ 'height': h - 120, 'scroll-x': 'auto' });
```

NOTE: You might need to recalculate the height also on `$(window).resize()`.